# Entity Framework Code First AddOrUpdate method SQL missing some entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have API ruuning as windows service with self host web api, that inserting entries one by one if they not exist.

My table is `Medication` with these columns:

```
UID (GUID) 
MedID (NVARCHAR)  
Name (NVARCHAR)  
Code (NVARCHAR)
```

If I'm getting medication with same `MedID` and `Code`, I'm only updating the entry, if not I'm creating new medication entity with new `UID` (the `UID` isn't received in API).

I'm running this method:

```
public bool AddUpdateMedication(Medication med)
{
        try
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                context.Medications.AddOrUpdate(med);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RaiseError(ex);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

I'm not getting any errors but some of the entries are not inserted into the database.

It's usually appends when I'm getting a lot of requests at the same time. It's not a problem in the API, I do see lines of "adding medication to DB with UID XXX-XXX....", but none exists in the database.

Theory: do I need to add `;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` in the connection string?

Comment: The documentation states that `AddOrUpdate` is recommended for seeding during migration only. I would be very hesitant to use it outside of that.

Comment: So what can replace `AddOrUpdate` method?

Comment: Ohh . it's not APS MVC, it's windows service with self host web api